# Multiple matches to variable in regex expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following sample log that i need to extract the values from

```
<unsetChoice>1449489  and  <setChoice>1449489
```

Some lines have more them one value (up to three I think)

```
<auditElement><field id="1399941" type="8" name="Privilege" formatstring=""><unsetChoice>1437844</unsetChoice></field></auditElement>
<auditElement><field id="1399941" type="8" name="Privilege" formatstring=""><unsetChoice>1449489</unsetChoice></field></auditElement>
<auditElement><field id="1399941" type="8" name="Privilege" formatstring=""><setChoice>1449489</setChoice><unsetChoice>1437844</unsetChoice></field></auditElement>
<auditElement><field id="1399941" type="8" name="Privilege" formatstring=""><setChoice>1437844</setChoice><unsetChoice>1449489</unsetChoice></field></auditElement>
<auditElement><field id="1399941" type="8" name="Privilege" formatstring=""><setChoice>1449489</setChoice></field></auditElement>
```

I have the Regex below, which i think should capture the lines with two values and does, it should allow search and replace to be used  with `\1 \t \2` and save each of the found data to new lines.  however lines having one values are ignored.

is there a method of addressing this?

```
.*(setChoice>[0-9]{1,}|unsetChoice>[0-9]{1,}).*(setChoice>[0-9]{1,}|unsetChoice>[0-9]{1,}).*
```

Full example here

https://regex101.com/r/lPuRut/1

Comment: Where are you using this regex? It'd be best to use an XML parser.

Comment: it is in notepad ++, the log is not an xml document. the application exports to an excel document. this is just one of fields of the document.

Comment: Maybe `<((?:un)?setChoice)>([0-9]+)</\1>` Then `\2` or `$2` will have your integer, not sure how notepad denotes captured values.

Comment: captured values are  reference with \1, \2 in notepad,  I will need experiment, is this reverse lookup?

Comment: The `\1` in the regex is a back reference to make sure the closing element is what was opened. What do you mean by `reverse lookup`?

Comment: Your current expression can be reduced to [`(?:.*?(?:un)?setChoice>[0-9]+){2}`](https://regex101.com/r/lPuRut/3) but I have no idea what you need as it will not find a match.

Comment: meant positive/negative lookbehind

Comment: Oh, nope no lookbehinds, nor aheads. The `?:` is a non-capture group it didn't seem important if the `un` was/wasn't present.

Comment: Success with that?